# If the product of two matrices is a null matrix, when can we say one of them is a null matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$A$ and $B$ are two rectangular matrices of size $m \times n$ and $n \times p$, respectively (where $n > m,p$). Also $A$ is full rank. If $AB = 0$ can we say $B = 0$?

Comment: No AB=0 not always implies A or B =0.

Comment: I know But when one of them is full rank what can we say.I think if A has full column rank then B should be null matrice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example is to pick $ A $ to have one row and $ B $ one column ($ m = p = 1 $).  $ A B $ then becomes a dot product, and we know that for any two orthogonal vectors their dot product is $ 0 $.

This is the kind of example that is important to think about, since it shows that a lot of what you know about algebra with scalars does not carry over to algebra with matrices.

Comment: Do you know the answer  for the case $n  <  $m , $p

Comment: What you are asking is:  If $ A $ has linearly independent columns, does $ A B = 0 $ mean $ B $ is the zero matrix.  The answer is yes.  How do you see that?  $ A B = A ( b_0 ~~ b_1 ~~ \cdots ) = ( A b_0 ~~ A b_1 ~~ \cdots )  $.  So, $ A b_j = 0 $.  But since $ A $ has linearly independent columns, $ b_j $ (each column of $ B $) is zero.

Comment: yes my question was exactly that: when we can say $ B = 0 $  
I understand .thanks alot